# sql query and concat is not working, error throwing on every change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have the following query but the concatenation is not working,

```
Select Distinct DateName(month ,DateAdd(month , Month(aih.ddl) , 0) - 1) as sMonth+'-'+
(year(aih.ddl)) as syear 
FROM ail
inner join aipd on aipd.ID = aih.OfferingID 
Where aih.typeIN ('A') AND aipd.pid= 5034
```

Comment: what concatenation?

Comment: need to join both fields as one field

Comment: remove `as sMonth` & make sure you concat a string: `cast(year(aih.ddl) as varchar(4))`

Answer (score 1):

```
DateName(month ,DateAdd(month , Month(aih.ddl) , 0) - 1) as sMonth+'-'+
(year(aih.ddl)) as syear
```

Few issues with your code..

`DateName(month ,DateAdd(month , Month(aih.ddl) , 0) - 1)` is  varchar
`(year(aih.ddl))` will be int
`-` is also a varchar

so do `cast(year(somevalue) as varchar(4))` to avoid errors..

As Alex mentions in his comment below,you will need to do provide  final alias,not intermediate aliases ..while concatenating

```
DateName(month ,DateAdd(month , Month(aih.ddl) , 0) - 1) +'-'+
(year(aih.ddl)) as 'column name you want to choose'
```

Comment: You cannot have a `+` after an alias